# How to use the value of the variable?

Tags: jquery, events, variables, click

I do have a variable named "movieTitle". I used it inside the click event, but how can I use the value of that variable when I use it inside a function that is outside the event?

```
function addMovie(){
   $("Movie title is "+ movieTitle).appendTo("#output");
}

$("#insert").click(function(){
   var movieTitle = $("input#movie").val();
   addMovie();
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't pass the movieTitle variable to the addMovie function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass it as argument:

```
function addMovie(movieTitle){
   $("#output").append("Movie title is "+ movieTitle).
}

$("#insert").click(function(){
   addMovie($("#movie").val());
})
```